# Adding a photo directly to iPhone disk

Tags: iphone, hard-drive, photos

I tried to add a picture in the folder `/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/` (the same as `/private/var/mobile/DCIM/100APPLE/`), but it doesn't show up in the Camera Roll.

How can we make it appear?
It's an iPhone 3G running iOS 4.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice in [this forum thread](http://modmyi.com/forums/general-iphone-chat/409261-how-transfer-photos-pc-iphones-camera-roll.html), I've deleted the files (after backing up to the computer):

- `/User/Media/PhotoData/com.apple.photos.caches_metadata.plist`
- `/User/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite`
- `/User/Media/PhotoData/PhotosAux.sqlite`

After opening the Photos app again, it rebuilds the Library:

> [image: updating library]

It's important to use the pattern `IMG_0000.ext` for the pictures file names:

- `0000` being numeric ID of our choosing
- `.ext` is a JPG or PNG extension
- we can add letters after the numeric ID to prevent conflicts with the device ID counter, ie, `IMG_0041b.png`, `IMG_0041c.png`, `IMG_0041d.png`.