# How to import photos from PC to iPhone without iTunes, iDrive, iCloud?

Tags: iphone, photos

I would like to transfer photos from my notebook (Linux) to my iPhone (6s iOS 10).

Due to company restrictions on the device (AirWatch) I can't use iDrive or iCloud.

I tried to simply copy over the pictures, but the gallery application won't recognize them and I did not find a way to rescan the DCIM folder.

What other options are available to import photos from PC to iPhone without iTunes, iDrive, iCloud?

Comment: Would an acceptable option include using a 3rd-party app like Amazon Photos to view your images?

Comment: Unfortunately installing apps is impossible due to the restrictions imposed by my employer.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to simply copy over the pictures, but the gallery application won't recognize them and I did not find a way to rescan the DCIM folder.

Check the [question on “Adding a photo directly to iPhone disk”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125130/2184), and [its answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125131/2184) which suggests that Photos can be forced to rebuild its library by deleting the following files from `/User/Media/PhotoData/`: `com.apple.photos.caches_metadata.plist`, `Photos.sqlite` and `PhotosAux.sqlite`. The files that you added also need to be named according to the “IMG_1234.jpg” pattern. I haven’t tested this myself, and the question is a few years old, so this might no longer work on recent iOS versions though.

> What other options are available to import photos from PC to iPhone without iTunes, iDrive, iCloud? […] Unfortunately installing apps is impossible due to the restrictions imposed by my employer.

If it's just a few pictures, one option could be to email them to yourself, the Mail app allows saving all pictures in an e-mail (tap and hold one of them, then choose “Save [number] Images”; [WikiHow offers a more detailed explanation](http://www.wikihow.com/Save-Pictures-from-Emails-on-an-iPhone)). Another option could be to use an SD card or camera as an intermediary, though you'd have to get the [“Lightning to SD Card Camera Reader”](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJYT2AM/A/lightning-to-sd-card-camera-reader) or one of the [“Lightning to USB Camera Adapters”](https://www.apple.com/search/Lightning-USB-Camera-Adapter).

Comment: Would the phone need to be jailbroken to do this? I don't have access to /User/Media/PhotoData...

Comment: Sorry, I hadn’t considered that, as I didn’t test it and in fact, don’t have any experience in trying to access an iPhone’s files directly. The answer that I linked to doesn’t mention that it requires a jailbreak, but the answer does cite a forum thread on a site that’s about iPhone jailbreaking. It might be best to ask the user that posted that question&answer to clarify.